# Add multiple classes name to post thumbnail in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

this is a wordpress problem. I know I can add a class to a wordpress featured image via this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive']); ?>
```

However how do I add multiple? I tried using an array but it just displays array in inspecter and I am not sure if it worked. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try it simply like this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive my-other-class']); ?>
```

Comment: hahaha omg. I guess my common sense was absent there for a moment :) That did the trick. Thank you sir.